# Handle BLE user event on FreeRTOS

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, freertos, nucleo

I'm running FreeRTOS on a ST Nucleo board with the BlueNRG shield.
The initialization of the BLE stack works, the devices advertises itself and I can establish a connection. My problem is that as soon as user event arrives (e.g. service discovery) the program ends up in the `hardfault_handler()`.

I have 3 tasks running on my RTOS of which one should be a dedicated BLE task handling the user events.

```
void hci_user_evt_proc(void)
{
  tHciDataPacket * hciReadPacket = NULL;

  /* process any pending events read */
  while (list_is_empty(&hciReadPktRxQueue) == FALSE)
  {
    list_remove_head (&hciReadPktRxQueue, (tListNode **)&hciReadPacket);
    if (hciContext.UserEvtRx != NULL)
    {
      hciContext.UserEvtRx(hciReadPacket->dataBuff);
    }
    list_insert_tail(&hciReadPktPool, (tListNode *)hciReadPacket);
  }
}
```

This is taken from an ST example code.
The whole thing works if I either

- Just run this one task or
- Give the BLE task a higher priority

Both solutions have the same outcome - and don't have a multitasking system anymore.
I don't know if a have to adapt the example code to run in a multitask system or if I have to run the BLE process interrupt driven, but if yes, how would I do that and how can I elaborate the root cause of a `hardfault`?

What I tried is to surround my `user_evt_handler` with a `vTaskSuspendAll/xTaskResumeAll` but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue solved by giving the BLE task more stack size